# Solving integral equation using Laplace transform

Tags: integral-equations

$x(t)+\int_0^t(t-\tau)x(\tau)=t^2$

Is $x(\tau)$ the equivalent of $d\tau$?
How do I solve this particular equation?

Answer (score 1):

The $\,d\tau$ was just missing. That integral $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}(t-\tau)x(\tau)\,d\tau$ is $t$ convolved with $x(t)$.

Your first step should be to take the Laplace transform of both sides. Remember convolution in the time domain corresponds to multiplication in the Laplace domain.

$x(t) + \displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}(t-\tau)x(\tau)\,d\tau = t^2$

$X(s) + \dfrac{1}{s^2}X(s) = \dfrac{2}{s^3}$.

Now solve for $X(s)$.

Comment: I solved it and got $2(cos t -1)$. Is that the good answer? Shouldnt there be any arbitrary constant in it?

Comment: Try plugging in $x(t) = 2(\cos t - 1)$ and $x(t) = 2(\cos t - 1)+100$ into the integral equation and see which of them work.

Comment: Actually neither of them. I missed a minus sign somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laplace transform techniques. See [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140106/volterra-integral-equation-of-secong-type-solve-using-resolvent-kernel/425186#425186), [(II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408777/volterra-integral-equation-with-variable-boundaries).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Define:
$$y(t):=x(t)+\int_0^t(t-\tau)x(\tau)-t^2=0......(1)$$
Then
$$y''(t)=x''(t)+x(t)-2=0......(2)$$

You may then solve (2) for $x(t)$.

$$x(t)=2+c_1 \cos t+c_2\sin t$$